# Load HTML contents in Silverlight RichTextBox?

Tags: html, c#-4.0, richtextbox, asp.net-4.0, silverlight-5.0

see, i have a html file and i'm trying to load other than iframe and web-browser controls
so i used RichTextBox is it supportable only with XAML? if it also supports HTML.how do i implement.

i tried to load a html file but it loaded as text.

below is my code.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="400"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="580"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Canvas>
    <TextBox Height="23" x:Name="txtFileName" Canvas.Left="15" Canvas.Top="40" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="280"  />
        <Button Content="Browse" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="btnBrowse" Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="40" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="75" Click="BtnBrowse_Click"  />

        <RichTextBox x:Name="rtxtboxHTML" Margin="3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="450" Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="450" Canvas.Top="40" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

    </Canvas>
</Grid>

private void BtnBrowse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Html files (*.html)|*.htm|All Files (*.*)|*.*";

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog()==true)
        {
            txtFileName.Text = openFileDialog.File.Name;
            FileInfo _File = openFileDialog.File;

            using (StreamReader strReader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog.File.OpenRead()))
            {
                string _strTemp = string.Empty;
                //var rs = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(openFileDialog.File.Name, UriKind.Relative));
                //StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rs.Stream);
                while (!strReader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    _strTemp = strReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                strReader.Close();
                rtxtboxHTML.Selection.Text = _strTemp;
            }
        }
    }
```

where i went wrong...
Thank you

Comment: You might want to try HTML Agility Pack, if you need something exhaustive: https://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/locale/en-us/html/Microsoft%20Silverlight%20Release%20History.htm#SL_5_1_10411

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RichTextBox` will not parse HTML for you.